# Jqm Knockout checkbox does not bind

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js, bind, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to bind checkbox checked but it seems like it doesn't recognize the bind.

I'm applying bindings this way:

```
$("#crearFicha").live('pagebeforeshow', (event)->
    event.preventDefault();
    ko.applyBindings(CrearFichaVMI, $('#crearFicha')[0]);
)
$('#crearFicha').live('pageshow', (event)->
    $('#groupList5').listview(
                autodividers: true
                autodividersSelector: (li)->
                    oficial_id = li.context.dataset.oficial
                    out = ""
                    switch oficial_id
                        when "12" then out = "Independencia"
                        when "11" then out = "Huachipa"
                        else out = ""
                    out)
    $('#groupList5').listview('refresh')
    $('.seccion select').selectmenu('refresh')
    $('.seccionsli select').slider('refresh')
    $('input[type="radio"]').checkboxradio()
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').checkboxradio()
    return
)
```

and my html is the follow

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="pregunta-5-2" class="infoFicha">                  
    <input data-theme="e" data-content-theme="e"  id="pregunta-5-2-1" name="pregunta-5-2-1" type="checkbox" value="Luz" data-bind="checked:$root.serv_basic().respuestas"/>
    <label for="pregunta-5-2-1">Luz</label> 
    <input data-theme="e" data-content-theme="e"  id="pregunta-5-2-2" name="pregunta-5-2-2" type="checkbox" value="Agua" data-bind="checked:$root.serv_basic().respuestas"/>
    <label for="pregunta-5-2-2">Agua</label>    
    <input data-theme="e" data-content-theme="e"  id="pregunta-5-2-3" name="pregunta-5-2-3" type="checkbox" value="Desague" data-bind="checked:$root.serv_basic().respuestas"/>
    <label for="pregunta-5-2-3">Desag�e</label> 
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you add your viewmodel to the post? If it's something wrong with the actual definition of `respuestas` then it'll help us find it quicker.

Comment: Yeah I have a feeling that the real answer lies somewhere with the definition of `$root.serv_basic().respuestas` - does `serv_basic()` even have anything in it? is `respuestas` a boolean observable?